# Angular scrollPositionRestoration only works occasionally in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm currently setting `scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'` and implementing `RouteReuseStrategy` that only kicks in when users navigate via next/back button. In safari, `scrollPositionRestoration` returns to where i was every time. In chrome, some of the time it works, but most of the time it doesn't. I don't really know what's wrong so i'm not posting any codes.

Answer (score 0):

Until I find another way to solve this problem, this is the only solution I found:

-Just add this code to your **app-routing.module.ts** file,

```
constructor(router: Router, viewportScroller: ViewportScroller) {
router.events
  .pipe(filter((e): e is Scroll => e instanceof Scroll))
  .subscribe((e) => {
    if (e.position) {
      // backward navigation
      setTimeout(() => {
        viewportScroller.scrollToPosition(e.position);
      }, 0);
    } else if (e.anchor) {
      // anchor navigation
      console.log(e.anchor);
      viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor(e.anchor);
    } else {
      // forward navigation
      viewportScroller.scrollToPosition([0, 0]);
    }
  });
}
```